# Beacon interval low power mode

Tags: wireless-access-point, udp, multicast

I am creating a UDP multicast net using Ubiquiti Rocket M2. None of the hardware receivers (ESP 8266) are on lower power mode. The only (possibly) low power device that is connected to the AP is my Macbook (to properly sniff the packets) but is is not subscribed to the multicast net.

My question is, will the AP wait for Beacon interval packets to send UDP multicast data when a receiver on the multicast net is on low power mode or will it wait if any receiver, irrespective of whether it's on the multicast net or not, is on low power mode.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "subscribed to the multicast net", are you referring to using IGMP to tell the IP router(s) which multicast IP addresses you're interested in receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an AP has one or more clients in 802.11 power save mode, it will buffer multicasts (including broadcasts) until it transmits the next DTIM Beacon (DTIM intervals can be multiples of the Beacon Interval). The 802.11 standard is agnostic to layer 3 protocols such as IP, so it doesn't require IGMP Snooping. I am not aware of any AP implementation that employs IGMP Snooping to improve multicast delivery performance, but that sounds like a useful idea. 802.11 does not provide a link-layer mechanism by which clients can tell APs which multicast MAC addresses they wish to receive, so the AP has no way to know which multicasts a power-save-mode station may be interested in, so any time there's a client in power save mode, the AP must buffer all multicasts until the next DTIM.